# Can we set image width by percentage in ngx-masonry

Tags: angular, jquery-masonry, masonry, angular-masonry

When I'm trying add width by percentage, it's not working.
It's showing like image per row.

Is there any way to fix the issue ?

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<ngx-masonry [options]="options" [ordered]="true">
      <div ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item" *ngFor="let item of gallery"  [style.width.%]="[item.width]">
        <a class="" href="/assets/images/gallery/{{item.image}}" data-fancybox="gallery">
          <img src="/assets/images/gallery/{{item.image}}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
</ngx-masonry>
```

Ts Code:

```
public options: NgxMasonryOptions = {
    itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
    gutter: 10,
    resize: true,
};

public gallery = [
  {
    'image' : 'image1.jpg',
    'width' : '50%'
  },
 {
    'image' : 'image2.jpg',
    'width' : '25%'
  },
 {
    'image' : 'image3.jpg',
    'width' : '25%'
  },
 {
    'image' : 'image4.jpg',
    'width' : '50%'
  },
 {
    'image' : 'image5.jpg',
    'width' : '50%'
  }
]
```

[image]
Update
..............

I have updated my code to,

Ts

```
public options: NgxMasonryOptions = {
    itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
    gutter: 0,
    resize: true,
  };

  public gallery = [
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 50,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 25,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 25,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 25,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 25,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 25,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 25,
    },
    
  ]
```

HTML

```
<ngx-masonry [options]="options" [ordered]="true">
            <div ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item ratio ratio-1x1" *ngFor="let item of gallery"  [style.width.%]="[item.width]">
                <img src="{{ item.image }}" style="width: 100%;">
            </div>
</ngx-masonry>
```

It's not working properly
..........................................................................

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the "width" property to a string, e.g.

```js
'width' : '50%'
```

Short explanation:

Without a unit (e.g. `%` or `rem`) the value is interpreted as pixel based value and it is ok to use a number type for it. But when you want to set the unit behind the value (in this case `%`) you have to write it as string type.

**EDIT**

I missed the point that you already set the width as percantage value with `[style.width.%]="[item.width]"`. In this case the value for `width` is fine with just as a number without any unit.

I tried it out and it worked fine, even without `percentPostition` option.

**TS code**:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { NgxMasonryOptions } from 'ngx-masonry'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-masonry',
  templateUrl: './app-masonry.component.html',
})
export class AppMasonryComponent {

  public options: NgxMasonryOptions = {
    itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
    gutter: 0,
    resize: true,
  }

  public gallery = [
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 50,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 25,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 25,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
    {
      'image' : 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578133630261-a79a92922335?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=400&q=80&w=400',
      'width' : 12.5,
    },
  ]
}
```

**HTML code** (I additionally used `ratio` helper class from bootstrap to make the images square):

```html
<ngx-masonry [options]="options" [ordered]="true">
    <div ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item ratio ratio-1x1" *ngFor="let item of gallery"  [style.width.%]="[item.width]">
        <img src="{{ item.image }}">
    </div>
</ngx-masonry>
```

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the code, still facing same issue.

Comment: Did you set the [percentPosition option](https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#percentposition) to `true` ?

Comment: How can use percentPosition, could you please share a example?

Comment: I just edited the answer, works fine this way, even without `percentPosition: true`

Comment: Here is the documentation for the bootstrap [ratio helper class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/#aspect-ratios) if needed.

Comment: Hi bro, I have tried your code, i just edited the code, but it's not working properly. and i have updated my question.